# Power BI | DAX | How do I write a DAX formula that returns every category with a count of 1?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

The use case I have is a Power BI visual for every "reason" that only has a count of 1.

I can create a table within the table visual in the 'Report' page of Power BI desktop (similar to a pivot table in excel), but I want to create this same view within the 'Data' page in Power BI in a different Table or as a measure.

The process would be two-fold, 1) Perform a 'count' function for the "Reasons", and then 2) Filter it to only have every "Reasons" with a count of 1.

| Reasons | File Number |
| --- | --- |
| Reason 1 | X123 |
| Reason 2 | X124 |
| Reason 3 | X125 |
| Reason 4 | X126 |
| Reason 5 | X127 |
| Reason 6 | X128 |
| Reason 7 | X129 |
| Reason 8 | X130 |
| Reason 9 | X131 |
| Reason 10 | X132 |
| Reason 1 | X133 |
| Reason 1 | X134 |
| Reason 1 | X135 |
| Reason 1 | X136 |
| Reason 1 | X137 |
| Reason 1 | X138 |
| Reason 3 | X139 |
| Reason 3 | X140 |
| Reason 3 | X141 |
| Reason 3 | X142 |
| Reason 3 | X143 |
| Reason 3 | X144 |
| Reason 3 | X145 |
| Reason 3 | X146 |
| Reason 6 | X147 |
| Reason 6 | X148 |
| Reason 6 | X149 |
| Reason 6 | X150 |
| Reason 6 | X151 |
| Reason 6 | X152 |
| Reason 6 | X153 |
| Reason 6 | X154 |
| Reason 9 | X155 |
| Reason 9 | X156 |
| Reason 9 | X157 |
| Reason 9 | X158 |
| Reason 9 | X159 |
| Reason 9 | X160 |
| Reason 9 | X161 |
| Reason 9 | X162 |
| Reason 9 | X163 |
| Reason 10 | X164 |
| Reason 10 | X165 |
| Reason 10 | X166 |
| Reason 10 | X167 |
| Reason 10 | X168 |
| Reason 10 | X169 |
| Reason 10 | X170 |
| Reason 10 | X171 |

I tried using a 'Card' visual in Power BI and included the Reasons and turned it into a count. But, when I go to the 'Filters on this Visual' and try to manipulate the filtering to "Filter Type" = Top N, it is not an option to change it to 'IS = 1'.

I also tried going to the Data page and using the 'SUMMARIZE' function to return the distinct reasons, but it does not return a 'count' in a column next to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new calculated table as follows:

```
Table 2 = 
ADDCOLUMNS(
    SUMMARIZE('Table', 'Table'[Reasons]),
    "@Count", CALCULATE(COUNT('Table'[File Number]))
)
```

[image]

Or

```
Table 2 = 
FILTER(
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        SUMMARIZE('Table', 'Table'[Reasons]),
        "@Count", CALCULATE(COUNT('Table'[File Number]))
    ),
    [@Count] = 1
)
```

[image]